# How do I call google script triggers every second?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

Real-life problem is that I want to call api every X seconds and can't seem to accomplish it using Google scripts.

As I know you can call trigger in every 1, 5, 10, 15 or 30 minutes. 
Is there a way to run Google script every second?

```
  function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(1) //I can not write 0.01 instead of 1 here. 
      .create();
}

function myFunction() {
  Logger.log("Logging");
}

createTimeDrivenTriggers();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Time-based triggers:

You could use the method [after(durationMilliseconds)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer)) to call your function after a specified number of milliseconds, if you create the trigger at the end of your function, like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  Logger.log("Logging");
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .after(1000 * X) // Fire "myFunction" after X seconds
  .create();
}
```

But it seems this method (at least currently) cannot be used for firing a function after much less than a minute, as you can see in [this Issue Tracker case](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148240982).

Apart from this, **there is no time-based trigger that can be used for your purpose**.

#### Workaround:

Another option, if you just want to perform some actions after X seconds, would be to use [Utilities.sleep(milliseconds)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds) and a `for` loop.

Of course, you would eventually reach Apps Script [execution time limit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations), and for this reason you should:

- Find out how many iterations you can make before reaching this limit.
- Make each execution make this number of iterations.
- Create a trigger that will fire your function after a certain amount of time, with `after(durationMilliseconds)`.

It could be something similar to this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var numIterations = 10; // Number of iterations before reaching time limit (change accordingly)
  for (var i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
    // Your actions
    Utilities.sleep(1000 * X); // Pause execution for X seconds
  }
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .after(1000 * Y) // Fire "myFunction" after Y seconds
  .create();
}
```

This way, you can keep your desired frecuency most of the time, and only when the execution time limit is reached (every 6 or every 30 minutes, depending on your account) this frecuency will once be lower (around 1 minute), before going back to the desired frecuency. It's not the behaviour you expect, but I think it's the closest you can get to it.

#### Reference:

- [after(durationMilliseconds)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#after(Integer))
- [Issue Tracker: Time based trigger could not fire after few seconds](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148240982)
- [Utilities.sleep(milliseconds)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds)